# Union of subsets inside product space

Tags: general-topology

In one paper I saw the following situation.

We have two topological pairs $(S^1,x_0)$ and $(S^1,x_0)$. Then we take $X=(S^1\times \{x_0\})\cup (\{x_0\}\times S^1)$ "taken as union inside $S^1\times S^1$". Somehow it is stated that $X=S^1\vee S^1$. Why is it true? For me it still looks like just a union of 2 circles. Or these two circles are considered to be two copies of one same circle? Then don't we have to get just $X=S^1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s clearer if we change the notation to keep track of the pairs $\langle S^1,x_0\rangle$: let them be $\langle Y,y_0\rangle$ and $\langle Z,z_0\rangle$. Then

$$X=(Y\times\{z_0\})\cup(\{y_0\}\times Z)\subseteq Y\times Z\;,$$

where $Y\times Z$ is simply $S^1\times S^1$ under a different name. $X$ can be thought of as the union of the two colored circles in [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#/media/File:Torus_cycles.svg); the point where they intersect corresponds to the point $\langle y_0,z_0\rangle$ in $Y\times Z$. Thus, $X$ really is just the wedge sum of two copies of $S^1$: it’s homeomorphic to the space obtained from $Y\cup Z$ by identifying $\{y_0,z_0\}$ to a point.

Comment: But how can we know that $X$ must be union of exactly these circles? If we did not have the answer known, how would we understand that $X$ is not union of any 2 circles from this picture: https://www.google.com/search?q=torus+with+2+circles&sxsrf=ALeKk02wBq1e4ReNtFi84T4xLEYM0tEp_g:1589144301613&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSouDsl6rpAhWh16YKHZ6IBbYQ_AUoAXoECA4QAw&biw=1600&bih=767#imgrc=Ll2hWY7bHOgcNM

Comment: @Haldot: I don’t know which of the pictures there you have in mind. In any case, if you visualize $Y\times Z$ as a physical torus, $X$ is **by construction** the union of two circles just like the ones in the picture to which I linked; which two depends entirely on which point of the product is $\langle y_0,z_0\rangle$.

Comment: Oh, I thought the link led to a specific picture. Anyway, I meant 2 circles, which both are on the torus, but don't intersect. If torus is surface of a finger, then these would be 2 rings on that finger.

Comment: @Haldot: The construction ensures that the circles intersect at $\langle y_0,z_0\rangle$, so they simply can’t be like two rings on a finger.

Comment: Oh, waaaait, I think I finally got it. The key point is that we take $(Y\times\{z_0\})\cup (\{y_0\}\times Z)$ and not just $Y \cup Z$, right? Sets $(x,z_0)$ and $(y_0,y)$, where $x$ and $y$ run through all point on circle, obviously, must intersect. I kinda ignored points in the products before. Thanks!

Comment: @Haldot: Yep, now you’ve got it; you’re welcome!

Comment: @Haldot  out of curioisty, on what paper you saw this? can you share the paper ?

Comment: @ILoveMath This paper: http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/jg1u11/Papers/CXX.pdf, the very beginning of the second page. However, I simplified it in order to avoid unnecessary information. Basically, my question is equivalent to "if simplicial complex $K$ is disjoint union of $2$ points, then polyhedral product $(S^1,pt)^K$ is wedge of two circles".